# client side sorting using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting, client-side

Ive been trying to build a web site that retrieves values from the database and then implements features such as sorting and filtering. I am building the query each time a filter is applied as of now, will definitely change to something more efficient. For the sorting, I want to implement it on the client side itself since the data is already present.

I went through a number posts from this forum and arrived at a piece of code that I included in mine. To give you a heads up on the web page, the sorting options are included as radio buttons. Whenever a user clicks on the "Apply" button, a javascript function is triggered which sorts the html table - which is populated using php.

Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SortTable() {
            var sortedOn = 1;
            var table = document.getElementById('venue_list');
            var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var rowArray = new Array();
            for (var i=0, length=rows.length; i<length; i++) {
                rowArray[i] = new Object;
                rowArray[i].oldIndex = i;
                rowArray[i].value = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[sortOn].firstChild.nodeValue;
            }
            //if (sortOn == sortedOn) { rowArray.reverse(); }
            //else { sortedOn = sortOn; }
            /*
                Decide which function to use from the three:RowCompareNumbers,
                RowCompareDollars or RowCompare (default).
                For first column, I needed numeric comparison.
            */
            if (sortedOn == 1) {
                rowArray.sort(RowCompareStrings);
            }
            else {
                rowArray.sort(RowCompare);
            }
            var newTbody = document.createElement('tbody');
            for (var i=0, length=rowArray.length ; i<length; i++) {
                newTbody.appendChild(rows[rowArray[i].oldIndex].cloneNode(true));
            }
            table.replaceChild(newTbody, tbody);
        }
        function RowCompare(a, b) {
            var aVal = a.value;
            var bVal = b.value;
            return (aVal == bVal ? 0 : (aVal > bVal ? 1 : -1));
        }   
        // Compare Strings
        function RowCompareStrings(a, b) {
            var index = b.localeCompare(a);
            return index;
        }
    </script>
    <div style="float: right;margin-right: -100px;" class="box2">
            <h2>Sort by :</h2>
            <input type="radio" id="s1" name="sort" value="1" />
            <label for="f1"><?php echo 'Name'?></label>
            <input type="radio" id="s1" name="sort" value="1" />
            <label for="f1"><?php echo 'Location'?></label>
            <br><br><br>
            <div id="ContactForm" action="#">
                <input name="sort_button" value="Apply"  type = "button" id="sort_button"  class="button" onclick="SortTable();"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                            $name = $row['NAME'];
                            $img = $row['IMAGE_SRC'];
                            $addr = $row['ADDRESS'];
                            $location = $row['LOCATION'];

                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>map_function('{$addr}','{$name}','{$img}');</script>";
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $name?>">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $img.".jpg"?>" height="100" width="100">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $name?>">
                                        <h3><?php echo $name?></h3>
                                    </a>
                                <td>
                            </tr>                       
                        <?php
                        }
                    ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

For now, I'm fixing the sorting column number, sortedOn to 1 just to check if its working but to my dismay it is not. I have been trying to get it work since quite some time now. I am relatively new to Javascript and this is my first take on web development. Looking forward to a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have a PHP syntax error. I assume this has nothing to do with your problem so I edited your question.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to sort the rows of a table with javascript, you can implement `sortable.js`.

http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

I would recommend you that convert your query result to Json format using PHP `json_encode()`, this way you can deal with javascript all data in a more simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to figure out my mistake. There were multiple errors in the javascript function. Secondly the  in the table was missing for the second column. In the javascript function, basically, I was comparing the rowArray objects themselves in the RowCompareStrings function. I should actually be comapring the rowArray.value with each other.